# Can't draw BufferedImage into another BufferedImage with scale

Tags: java, awt

Please advise.

I'm trying to draw input BufferedImage into larger output BufferedImage (with scaling). Please, take a look at the following code:

```
public class Main {
    public void print(BufferedImage img, int width, int height) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                System.out.print(img.getRGB(x, y) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main app = new Main();

        // create input image
        int inputWidth = 2;
        int inputHeight = 2;
        BufferedImage inputImg = new BufferedImage(inputWidth, inputHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        // fill input image
        for (int y = 0; y < inputHeight; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < inputWidth; x++) {
                inputImg.setRGB(x, y, y * inputWidth * (1 << 16) + x);
            }
        }

        // print
        app.print(inputImg, inputWidth, inputHeight);

        // create output image
        int outputWidth = 4;
        int outputHeight = 4;
        BufferedImage outputImg = new BufferedImage(outputWidth, outputHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        // draw inputImg into outputImg
        Graphics2D g = outputImg.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(inputImg, 0, 0, outputImg.getWidth(), outputImg.getHeight(), 0, 0, inputImg.getWidth(), inputImg.getHeight(), null);

        // print
        app.print(outputImg, outputImg.getWidth(), outputImg.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Execution produces the following output:

```
0 1 
131072 131073 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
```

Seems like Graphics2D object works, because I'm able to draw, for example, a line calling the drawLine function. So, I think the inputImg is the source of the issue, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

UPDATE:
I've tried to use `AffineTransform`, but it didn't help, unfortunately.

```
Graphics2D g = outputImg.createGraphics();
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.setToIdentity();
at.scale(2, 2);
g.drawImage(inputImg, at, null);
```

Comment: Do you have to manually scale the image?  `Graphcs2D` has `AffineTransform` which can perform scaling operations

Comment: Documentation says that this version of drawImage should scale inputImage on the fly [drawImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver))

Comment: Yeah, that's nice, any reason you can't use `AffineTransform`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried to use `drawImage` version that accepts `AffineTransform`, but it didn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: I substitute your color algorithm for `Color.RED.getRGB()`, it generates a result - forgive me for having a useless understand of color mathematics, but the `BufferedImage` is expecting a value of RGBA - I'd make sure the alpha value is been included in your calculations

Comment: @MadProgrammer you're right! The issue is an alpha value. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The reason I keep suggesting `AffineTransform` is because it can generate a nicer result, but that comes down to your own needs, that's all :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, this seems to be an issue with the color calculation you're using...

When I change...

```
inputImg.setRGB(x, y, y * inputWidth * (1 << 16) + x);
```

to...

```
int rgb = y * inputWidth * (1 << 16) + x;
inputImg.setRGB(x, y, new Color(rgb).getRGB());
```

I get a result, albeit a black dot.  This suggests to me that by default, your calculation is generating a `alpha` value of `0`

This can be born out in the output that they produce:

My method generates

```
-16777216 -16777215 
-16646144 -16646143
```

Yours generates

```
0 1 
131072 131073
```

Now, frankly, this is why I don't do this kind of calculation, not when a API is available to do it for me - but I be dumb ;P

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public void print(BufferedImage img, int width, int height) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                System.out.print(img.getRGB(x, y) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main app = new Main();

        // create input image
        int inputWidth = 2;
        int inputHeight = 2;
        BufferedImage inputImg = new BufferedImage(inputWidth, inputHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        // fill input image
        System.out.println(inputWidth + "x" + inputHeight);
        Color color = Color.RED;
        for (int y = 0; y < inputHeight; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < inputWidth; x++) {
                int rgb = y * inputWidth * (1 << 16) + x;
                inputImg.setRGB(x, y, new Color(rgb).getRGB());
            }
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(inputImg)));

        // print
        app.print(inputImg, inputWidth, inputHeight);

        // create output image
        int outputWidth = 4;
        int outputHeight = 4;
        BufferedImage outputImg = new BufferedImage(outputWidth, outputHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        // draw inputImg into outputImg
        Graphics2D g = outputImg.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(inputImg, 0, 0, outputImg.getWidth(), outputImg.getHeight(), 0, 0, inputImg.getWidth(), inputImg.getHeight(), null);
        g.dispose();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(outputImg)));

        // print
        app.print(outputImg, outputImg.getWidth(), outputImg.getHeight());
    }
}
```